# Pulling login information from windows authentication IIS for PHP application

Tags: php, authentication, iis, web-config

I have an IIS 8 webserver hosting a PHP web application. There is a management page that requires windows authentication via the web.config file.

Is there any way to pull any identifying information that could be passed to the PHP application?

I've tried pulling the headers but nothing in there seems of any use. At one point I did get some identifying information in the cookie but that is not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these did the trick:

```
$_SERVER['LOGON_USER'];
$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
```